# How do I integrate google OAuth with java servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have already created a web project (not in google app engine) and at last wanted to integrate Googe OAuth with my existing web project.Will I be needing Google Engine Plugin for Eclipse or can it be done using just google-appengine and google-sdk jars?I have gone through many links, many of them suggest about creating a maven project which destroys my project structure.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you almost never need an eclipse plugin to do something (NB: I don't say that plugins are useless)

Answer (score 1):

No you technically do not need any of the google jars because OAuth is a protocol, not a program of sorts. Google jars may however simplify your application.

If you want to write it from scratch, please refer to [google's website](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) about it. This website also provides clients which, and I quote from the given link:

> Note: Given the security implications of getting the implementation
>   correct, we strongly encourage you to use OAuth 2.0 libraries when
>   interacting with Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints. It is a best practice
>   to use well-debugged code provided by others, and it will help you
>   protect yourself and your users. For more information, see Client
>   libraries.